# mysql select statement display multiple

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

Is there a way to make this series of data.

**close to output**

```
    Customer    Products
    C1          Chicken
    C1          Burger
    C1          Fries
    C2          Chicken
    C2          Coke
```

**desired output**

```
    Customer    Product
    C1          Chicken
                Burger
                Fries
    C2          Chicken
                Coke
```

currently I know how to make the first set of data appear but I want to know if the second one is possible.

EDIT: Customer is under a different table from the Products

Comment: Sorry, its my first time using this and I'm an MySQL newbie. I do want to write a query (A Select Statement)

Comment: ok, please post the table create statements for Customer and Products and some sample data ( which matches the desired output ). and also include the sql for the first set of data. also specify the context of this output ( webpage or mysql shell or other )